# IDE para desenvolvimento em VueJS

Tags: vue.js

Estou a iniciar-me no vueJS e gostava de saber que IDE aconselham?
Eu uso o netbeans para HTML, PHP, JS, etc. Dá para integrar o vueJS no netbeans?
Existem alguns pluing para isso?

Comment: Eu uso o Atom, há mais 2 sugestões aqui: https://forum.vuejs.org/t/what-text-editor-ide-works-with-vue-files/2221/3

Answer (score 2):

**Alguns editores de vueJS:**

- [Atom408](https://atom.io) com [language-vue730](https://atom.io/packages/language-vue)
- [Sublime Text](https://www.sublimetext.com/3) 3203 com [vue-syntax-highlight432](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-syntax-highlight)
- Vim ou [Neovim213](https://neovim.io/) com [vim-vue214](https://github.com/posva/vim-vue)

**Uso Pessoal**

Eu particulamente utilizo o Sublime, acho bem leve e gosto muito dos atalhos que ele proporciona.

**vue no Netbeans**

O arquivo .vue é um tipo de arquivo html, você pode adicionar destaque de sintaxe no Netbeans:

Tools > Options > Miscellaneous > Files

Adicione uma nova extensão de arquivo:
Extensão de arquivo: vue
Tipo de arquivo associado (MIME): arquivos HTML (texto / html)
Não é perfeito, mas parece que não há nenhum plugin realizar algo melhor que isso.